# Postpositions in English and "ago"

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech

I was informed earlier today that the word *ago* is actually a *postposition* and the only one  of its kind in English. Is this correct? If so, why do [dictionaries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ago) not use this classification and prefer to [label it an adverb](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ago) instead?

Comment: We don’t have many left-branching forms in English, but the productive *-wards* suffix can also be seen as an enclitic postposition.

Comment: Umm. What use is a linguistic classification category that has only one member?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Accuracy? I also don't know if it is the only member. It might not be.

Comment: David Crystal has a helpful blog post on this question: [link](http://david-crystal.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/on-postpositions.html)

Comment: Per [this link](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/postpositionterm.htm), in *"three weeks hence"*, it seems to me *"hence"* is used "postpositionally".

Comment: @FumbleFingers And yet *later* is classed as an adverb in *three weeks later*.

Comment: @tchrist: I thought we'd established long ago that "adverb" is often just a general-purpose "bucket category" for people who insist every (specific usage of a) word must fall into some particular category/"part of speech".

Comment: ...and especially where they additionally insist that the number of "parts of speech" must be pitifully small, preferably ignoring all advances in the study of syntax since the Victorian era :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some sources (see [Nordquist's article, especially the reference to Allerton's work](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/postpositionterm.htm)) do list ago as English's sole postposition, but there are actually quite a few other words that pattern the same way:

- hence: *five weeks hence*

and the following words, and others, have senses where they follow this usage, although otherwise they are prepositions and/or adjectives:

- through: *the whole day through*
- (a)round: *the world around*
- away: *ten miles away*
- wide: *four feet wide*
- long: *ten feet long*
- high: *eight miles high*

It's interesting that these all seem to result in phrases that act as adverbs of temporal or spatial extent.

Comment: I'd have thought there are many more contexts where other "prepositions" can be "postpositioned". I see nothing unusual in *"ten miles **off**"*, *"ten miles **out**"*, *"six inches **in**"*, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right, it's not really limited to the list above.

Comment: I think this another one of those contexts where grammatical terminology can be misleading. Perhaps we should have called them all [adpositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adpositional_phrase), but it's probably a bit late for that now.

Comment: Consider adverbial *late* or *later*: It arrived a day late and a mile short.  Just two weeks later, everything fell apart.

Comment: Thank you. Those are excellent examples. It seems to me that _ago_ is the only one which is _only_ used as a postposition. Would this be a fair contention?

Comment: @coleopterist No, enclitic *-wards* is also used only in that fashion.

Comment: @tchrist: Assuming I understand what you mean by *enclitic* there, does not the same apply to, for example, ["repeat {something} parrot-fashion"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22repeat+it+parrot+fashion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)? Or ["walk crab-wise"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22walk+crab+wise%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers But *-fashion* and *-wise* are run-of-the-mill “mannerly” left-branching affixes like *-ly*, whereas *-wards* is a left-branching **directional** affix. An important difference between a bound morpheme and an unbound one is that the clitic does not distribute across the entire phrase, whereas the free-standing adpositions do.  In both “Just three years ago” and “over/during/for the last three years”, the freestander applies itself to the whole phrase, but if you are inclined Queenwards, the *-wards* applies only to the Queen itself — ***unless*** you have suspension hyphens.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even calling them *adpositions* is misleading, since in English they often are separated from their objects: "The man you were talking about was here."

Comment: @tchrist Thank you. Particularly _-wards_ or _-ward_ as well? By suspension hyphen, do you mean something like _homeward-bound_?

Comment: @coleopterist It turns out that *-wards* and *-ward* have always been mostly synonymous. This is probably worth a question of its own. OED says: "In English the history of *-wards* as an advb. suffix is identical with that of *-ward* (see -ward 3 and 4); beside every adv. in *-ward* there has always existed (at least potentially) a parallel formation in *-wards*, and vice versa. The two forms are so nearly synonymous .. that the choice between them is mostly determined by [..] euphony in the particular context; some persons, apparently, have a fixed preference for the one or the other form.

Comment: @coleopterist By suspension hyphens, I mean factoring out the common bit by turning something like "1670 T. Brooks London’s Lament. 124 ― Yet the bent of their hearts will still be God-wards, Christ-wards, Heaven-wards, and Holiness-wards." into "Yet the bent of their hearts will still be God-, Christ-, Heaven-, and Holiness-wards." That is called "suspension hyphens" when you do that in English.

Comment: N.B. with "wide", "high" etc: (a) you can say "three feet higher" etc, whereas prepositions (and postpositions) are canonically invariable; (b) you can say "three and four feet wide and high respectively", whereas you can't readily say e.g. "the river and forest across and through respectively" (or "across and through respectively the river and forest").

Comment: Can I add '**past**' in the 'ago' sense to your helpful list. _He finished that job weeks past._ (AHD, M-W) (who miscategorise the usage).

Answer (score 3):

Prepositions are a class of words. The prefix *pre-* refers to the
fact that in languages such as English prepositions occur before
their complements — or, as ESL writers and old-fashioned grammars
like to say, before their objects:

- in the park
- like a hurricane

Typically prepositions take nouns or noun phrases as complements. In the examples above, *the park* and *a hurricane* are the complements of the prepositions *in* and *like*.

Modern grammar, however, recognises that prepositions can take many different types
of complement, or may take none at all. In the following examples we see prepositions which are taking different types of complement:

- Let’s meet *before* the concert starts.
- Let’s meet *after* the concert.
- Take it *out* of the box.
- I’ve never seen this *before*.

The first is taking a clause, the second a noun phrase, the third another prepositional phrase and the last has no complement. Previously, these prepositions had been thought to be different types of word in each case (adverbs, subordinating conjunctions, complex prepositions), but many straightforward tests show this is not so (cf. Huddleston and Pullum, 2002,  *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*).

Right, so back to words *ago* and *away*. These prepositions do not take nouns as complements or as objects. This is easier to show with the preposition *away*. Consider the phrase:

- forty miles away.

It is very tempting to imagine here that *forty miles* is the complement
of *away*, but it is not! Consider the phrase:

- forty miles away from Edinburgh.

Here the complement of *away* is the preposition phrase *from Edinburgh*.

If we think about it carefully, the phrase *forty miles* is modifying
the meaning of *away*; it is not one of the two things that the
preposition is showing a relationship between (the two things are:
*Edinburgh* and the place or event that Edinburgh was far from).

Typically, prepositions usually show a relationship between two entities.
These entities may be objects, events, times, people or ideas. The thing
we are already talking about is usually already referred to in the
sentence. The entity we are relating it to is usually the complement
or occurs within the complement phrase.

However, this isn’t always the case. With prepositions such as
*inside* the second entity is not always expressed, we mentally
reconstruct it:

- I'll see you inside (the cafe).

With the prepositions *away* and *ago* the second entity is the place or time we have
previously been thinking about: often here or now. As with *inside*, these entities
are usually not expressed in the sentence. The phrases that modify these prepositions do not function syntactically or semantically as the objects of the
prepositions but as their modifiers. So, in fact, *away* and *ago*  are not actually postpositions, unlike those prepositions which in many other languages come after their complements.

However, on the other hand, there is a strong case that in the phrases *the world around* and *the whole day through*, that *around* and *through*
are indeed occurring after their complements, and so could viably be termed ‘postpositions’.

In answer to the problem of why dictionaries do not usually
refer to those prepositions which do not take nouns as prepositions -
it is because they have so far ignored all of the advances that
have been made in modern English grammar! For a good introduction
into prepositions, I recommend Bas Aarts, 2011, *Oxford Modern English
Grammar*, which is clear and easy to understand.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: This needs paragraphs. A wall of text like this is very hard to read online. I'm tempted to do it myself and add italics where necessary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The main problem is that this user does not understand that hitting return here does not trigger a paragraph break.  The secondary problem is the lack of italics and other niceties.  The tertiary problem is that some of the would-be paragraphs are still too long, and need some restructuring. I have attempted to remedy these ills as well as possible without rewriting anything. Mostly they just need to learn that a return is not a paragraph marker: a blank line is, which needs two returns, not one.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by saying that you cannot see what  you’re typing. The answer box has a display beneath it for how it looks formatted. Why you would ever type anything at all in Word, I have no idea.

Comment: A good post! :) -- Though, since you mentioned the 2002 *CGEL*, you might like to know that they analyze "ago" as a preposition--due to that it takes a complement (which happens to be located before it)--pages 632, 697. E.g. *"She died [ten years ago]."*

Comment: @F.E. Thanks:) Yes, that's right. Their thinking is that the preceding phrase, usually an NP or _long_ is obligatory, so therefore they analyse it as a complement. However, there are other types of obligatory modification which we don't regard as being complementation. Their comparative analysis of _on_ in [_ten years on_] doesn't help their case here because it could easily read [_ten years on from that event_], which makes _on_ have one preceding and one following 'complement'. It does seem (imo) that the preceding one is modifying the preposition, or in any case has a different function...

Comment: They consider those two cases ("ten years on" versus "ten years ago") to be different because the expression "ten years" is an optional modifier for the preposition "on", while such an expression is obligatory for "ago" which indicates that it has the status of a complement.

Comment: @F.E. That's what I remembered originally, but actually they contrast "ten years before" and liken "ten years on". In their last para:" _On_, in the sense that it has..cannot occur without the accompanying phrase: _On, nothing had changed_ " The example there's meant to be ungrammatical. Phrases like _100 years ago from when?_ and _Our honeymoon was ten years ago from next Tuesday_ seem to be viable, interestingly.

Comment: What _is_ **unhelpful** is the implication that there is now a consensus amongst grammarians. 'as ... old-fashioned grammars like to say' BUT 'Modern grammar, however, recognises that ...'. [Cappelle](http://stl.recherche.univ-lille3.fr/sitespersonnels/cappelle/Pdf%20versions%20of%20papers/The%20particularity%20of%20particles.pdf) refutes the claim that 'many straightforward tests show this [ie that 'these words are all prepositions'] is not so':  '... the proved falsity of the claim [that] some particles, namely directional ones, are just [types] of prepositions'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth +1 While your point's interesting, I think that we could agree that particles from vernacularly so-called phrasal verbs would be an exception to the general observation, that we have for years been absolutely baselessly assigning prepositions to other categories according to their complementation -a fact which should be profoundly embarrassing to us.  I agree with you, Capelle provides claims which must be answered in relation to the argument that particles are a subset of prepositions. However, I think it would be rather overstating the case to say that he has ***refuted*** it!

Comment: (B) AHD agrees with me that it wouldn't: 1. To prove to be false or erroneous; overthrow by argument or proof: refute testimony.
2. **To deny the accuracy or truth of**: refuted the results of the poll. >>(Handy verb for connotation, though). //  (A)  Capelle here is not only using the word 'particle' in one of its most restricted (but I agree, perhaps its best known) sense of 'non-verby bit of a multi-word verb', but in the wider sense shown here: <(19') a. She carried the logs in. b. She carried in the logs. ('Carry in' is hardly undecomposable / unitary.)> cf 'I’ve never seen this before'.

Comment: ... Telmo Móia in their article [Telling apart temporal locating adverbials
and time-denoting expressions](http://aclweb.org/anthology//W/W01/W01-1306.pdf) uses the word 'particle' in this extended sense: '... These are namely the structurally complex expressions headed by the English particles before, after, between, when, ago, or from'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If it's that merely that type of refuting then I don't disagree!!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you look at C's example above the grammaticality judgement is a bit dubious in those instances. He's ignored in this paper loads of basic well known considerations like the comparative weight of the 'particle' phrases and objects. Note that he isn't able to come up with any two straight examples with homophonous particles and prepositions to differentiate the two. One of them is always idiomatic... I have to say though that I need to read it slowly while I'm not doing something else... Will have a look at the Telmo Moia a bit later. Thanks!

Comment: I'm awaiting a response from John Lawler in this area, but I'm beginning to think that the temporal modifiers in (a) I’d never seen this before. (b) I’d never seen this before the war. (a) I’d never seen this before he died. ... are better just labelled as adverbials of time. They all have the same function, though of course with differing degrees of explicit specificity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Try reading the section in the CaGEL pp 598-616. It deals with the general categorisation of prepositions,  as well as giving a detailed comparison of prepositions versus other word classes including adverbs in particular. It's pretty downright convincing imo. Karen who gave the answer below asked the question as a proper question here: [link] <http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174999/why-would-you-call-before-a-preposition-when-it-precedes-a-clause> .I'll be posting an answer when I finish my work!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry that was phrased wrong: should read 
 Well, adverbial really *is* a function label meaning sentence adjunct, not a part of speech or category of word of phrase. So I'd agree with your intuitions about that. But it can't a substitute for a part of speech assignation, I don't think

Comment: Been through the CGEL arguments; remain very unconvinced. Reminds me of the 'adverb catchall' lumping errors.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Really? It's specifically set out to right exactly that problem! Oh well, if we all agreed it would be a dull, dull world  :) Can you actually fault any of their argument? or counter it? I'm asking because it would be very interesting.

Comment: There is plenty in Cappelle. I'd just point out that 'the tourists walked around' would not be considered as a sensible ellipsis of 'the tourists walked around the lake'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Who is Bert Cappelle? -- Is he an EFL speaker? -- I've on page 5 of that paper you linked to, and, there are a bunch of errors so far. (And it seems that he misrepresented *CGEL*'s position on particles. Though, even I thought *CGEL*'s position was a bit unclear, even before this thread came up.) -- The paper is interesting, but more in an exercise sort of way. It seems that he might be fighting a straw-man.

Comment: I'd agree about ***walked around*** - a bit, but would still imply around something? the place? the space? the environment? But in any case we need an argument that works both syntactically and semantically, presumably?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For instance, Cappelle states on page 5 that *CGEL* claims *"that particles are in fact intransitive prepositions"*--of course *CGEL* can't make that claim, and as far as I know, they don't, since *CGEL* states that, on page 280: *"The most central particles are prepositions -- intransitive prepositions, of course, since they are on-word phrases. The class of particles also contains* **some adjectives and verbs,** *but they are restricted to a fairly small number of verbal idioms …"* And so, *CGEL* already realizes some particles are NOT prepositions. . . .

Comment: @F.E. Are you going to answer Karen below's question which she posted today? If so, I'll carry on with my very boring work. Otherwise will feel compelled to dive in and have a go...  But as SE's live-in H&P champion, I thought you might want to do it?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth . . .  -- Also, *CGEL* seems to consider particles are a "category". (Also on page 280.) -- (Aside: Maybe Cappelle's paper could deserve its own thread? If you want, you could open a question on it, and then people could, er, discuss some of his points. It might be interesting and fun.)

Comment: Nope, I'll let you have that fun! :) -- Yup, I be lazy. Yup, I be in the peanut gallery, with popcorn, yup I'll be watching, yup, yup.

Comment: No, they mean it as "category vs function". As in "NP vs subject of clause". -- *CGEL* doesn't use "part of speech" as traditional grammar does.

Comment: It's 7PM here, and since I'm retired, I stay up late . . . procrastinating . . . browsing . . .

Comment: @F.E.  it's just 'cuz they say 'defined by reference to structure [ia]', and the 'defined by structure' bit's making me a bit unsure...

Comment: @Araucaria Could you tell me what page in *CGEL* that you're referring to? ('Cause I'm not sure what the topic is.)

Comment: @F.E. I sent a query about whether H&P wanted to use 'category' as a word category (like Noun) or a function. Don't know where it's gone. Anyhow you replied as in your comment four comments above - "category versus function"...

Comment: Here are two related excerpts on page 280 (in the 2008 reprint) of *CGEL*: 1) "Since particles are here defined by reference to structure [ia], we will not invoke the category in intransitive clauses: …"; 2) The class of particles also contains some adjectives and verbs, but …" -- So, #1 implies particles as a category, but in #2 they refer to them as a class!? (shrugs) -- looking at that previous excerpt you did in a comment about 3 comments up, I'm wondering if you got that from *CGEL*, perhaps an older version? Printed in 2002, perhaps? Or am I the one with the older version?

Comment: Another directional example showing that the 'intransitive preposition' lumping is inadequate is 'You'll have to come over and see us sometime' where positing a suitable noun group would be very contentious (unless addressed to friends across the Channel, say). The synonymous '... come round and see us' is another.

Comment: @F.E. I've only done one quote, I think, which is a subsection of your 1). It's the concept of being 'defined by reference to a structure' that makes me think that they might be thinking of function, in the same way that they define 'determiners' as phrases fulfilling a function (ie with reference to the structure in NP) as opposed to 'determinatives' a lexical category (p. 54 penultimate paragraph). I've got the 2008 too! (I'm going to read it all one day!) –

Comment: Here's a simpler (though slightly different) illustration.'She ran in' is perfectly acceptable, and 'in' could be claimed to be a reduced prepositional phrase, an 'intransitive preposition' if you will. But as 'away', 'there', 'out' (UK) and 'home' are never prepositions, the structurally similar 'She ran away / there / out / home' are not analysable as reduced PP structures without ridiculous jiggery-pokery. I'm with BC in believing these have to go in another category: locative / directional particles.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But your doing that weird thing where you're analysing a part of speech by it's complements. Imagine doing that with a verb!! "This one's a verb because it has an NP as complement. This one's not because it takes a preposition, this one's not because it takes an *ing* verb form, this one's not because it takes a bare finite clause, this one isn't it takes a non-finite clause with *for*, this one isn't because it takes one with *to*. This one definitely isn't a verb it doesn't even have a complement!" Nobody on this side said that prepositions have to have nouns as complements!

Comment: So you just have a list that you've decided should be called prepositions? Of course distribution is a valid factor in determining POS. The dictionary definitions I've checked don't include any reference to prepositions/adpositions in general not governing a noun group. I'm prepared to accept better new theories, but they have to be unarguably better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm going to migrate my end of this discussion to <http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174999/why-would-you-call-before-a-preposition-when-it-precedes-a-clause> and delete most of my posts here. It's a bit overwhelming for any readers... Why don't you post an answer there?

Comment: There is an overview of the debate still surrounding the analyses of at least some structures involving particles [here](http://pure.hogent.be/portal/files/6011472/01_When_a_Linguist_Draws_a_Line_.pdf). (Declerck ‘s (1976b: 8))  counterarguments were later adopted and extended by Lindner (1981: 32), who concludes “that there is no line based on syntactic behavior which corresponds to an assumed line separating two discrete classes of literal and idiomatic combinations.”　
However, for the past thirty years, the phrasal verb debate has not abated,  and many linguists have had a say ...

Comment: about whether they are essentially words or word phrases and whether or not an answer to that question should depend on whether the combination is semantically transparent (literal) or not.　In Cappelle, Shtyrov and Pulvermüller (in preparation), it is suggested on the basis of a neuro-physiological experiment that phrasal verbs trigger brain responses similar to those associated with words, not phrases, and that these responses occur with both directional and semantically more abstract particles.

Comment: ... This appears to confirm Declerck’s and Lindner’s claim that 'walk in' and 'give up' should be seen “as instances of
the same phenomenon differing only in terms of semantic characteristics” (Lindner (1981: 31)). >> This is also 'Modern grammar' (though a different grammar from the one you mention as constituting 'Modern grammar') doing some recognising.

Comment: Well, about 35 years old, but this comment is off the topic anyhow... Although it's interesting...

Comment: Just found this: In their 2005 textbook, page 144, *"Some of the most common prepositions belonging to the particle category are listed in [37]: …"* -- And so, I guess it is safe to consider "particle" as one of their "categories". Though, I'm not sure if it is to be considered to be one of their "lexical categories". (When I was first reading *CGEL*, I think I was sorta assuming "particle" as more of a "function", a syntactic function within the structure of a clause. Anyhow . . . :)

Answer (score 1):

"ago" reminds me of German "vergangen" (passed by). 
The German question and answer might be" Wie lange ist das her? -- 20 Jahre sind vergangen.

In English this might be: When was it? -- 20 years have gone by.

Etymonline has old forms agan/agone (departed, passed away).

"agone" was shortened to ago. This explains why ago is placed after the time indication. It is still the structure of an old sentence like: Twenty years have/are agone". The new function word ago has the function of a preposition as in German vor 20 Jahren, but it is placed after the indication of the time span.
And now dictionaries have the problem of labelling the word class. Inventing a new term for this special word? Not very useful as FumbleFingers says. Etymonline says it is an adjective. Really?? There are other labels which are of no great value. The best thing is to understand the origin of this word, then the word class is of minor importance.

The best would be a special note: ago has the function of a preposition, but is in post-position because derived from a past participle.

Comment: OED says about this usage of the prefix *a-*, "expressing completeness ... attached to the past participle and occasionally to other parts of the verb."