# In, "Our nation declared independence 246 years ago tomorrow," precisely what does "tomorrow" modify?

Tags: prepositions

I recently stumbled upon an eight-year old comment by [Araucaria](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/76472/araucaria-not-here-any-more) in which they made the following statement in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/postpositions-in-english-and-ago#comment357497_171147) that was part of a discussion about post-positional phrases:

> Phrases like 100 years ago from when? and Our honeymoon was ten years ago from next Tuesday seem to be viable, interestingly.

That statement suggests doubt about whether the subject phrases are viable. They certainly are viable, but their internal construction is not clear.

Generally (the prime exception being cases of fronting), a PP modifies or complements a preceding phrase, which usually is the nearest preceding VP or an intervening NP. As examples: In *will play on the beach of my youth*, the PP *of my youth* adjectivally modifies the NP *the beach*.  In *will play on the beach next week*, the PP *next week* adverbially modifies the VP *will play*.

In *ten years ago next Tuesday*, we have an interesting syntactic puzzle. There are two PPs. The first is headed by the post-positional *ago*, and the second is headed conventionally by *next*. Without the latter PP, it would be clear that the complement of *ago* is *ten years*.

How is this phrase structured? Does the PP *next Tuesday* look beyond the intervening preposition, *ago*, to adjectivally modify the NP *ten years*?  Does the PP *next Tuesday* adverbially modify the entirety of the PP *ten years ago*?  Or is there some better analysis?

A semantic analysis is somewhat revealing. The phrase describes a point in time that occurs ten years prior to the Tuesday immediately following the point in time at which the phrase is stated. We understand the preposition *ago* as being an instruction to count backwards in time.  We understand the NP *ten years* as telling us how far back to count. Normally, *ago* implies that the counting should start from now, the present day.  Here, we understand *next Tuesday* as specifying a different point in time from which to begin counting.

It seems clear that the phrase *next Tuesday* does not modify the duration *ten years*. That sort of modification would be non-sensical. Similarly, *next Tuesday* cannot properly be understood to modify the concept of the point in time that happens to be *ten years* prior to now. That leaves the possibility that *next Tuesday* modifies the preposition *ago*.

The semantics of the phrase suggest that the preposition *ago* takes two arguments, one argument that specifies the starting point for counting and the other argument, usually implied to be *now*, that specifies how far back to count. However, our traditional model of PPs allows for only one argument (the complement of the PP), not two arguments--except when a PP is pre-modified by an adverbial.

PPs can be modified by adverbials. Take, for instance, *nearly in the soup*. Based on semantics, the AdvP *nearly* does not seem to modify the NP *the soup*. Rather, it seems to modify either the entirety of the PP *in the soup* or solely the preposition *in*. My sense of the meaning is that *nearly* changes the meaning of *in* before *in* acts upon its complement *the soup*. This suggests *in* is taking two arguments.

So it seems that *nearly* acts as an adverbial adjunct to the preposition *in*. In parallel, perhaps it is valid to analyze the NP *next Tuesday* as functioning as an adverbial adjunct to the preposition *ago*.

On this basis, I argue that prepositions are capable of taking two arguments. One argument is the usual prepositional phrase complement that imbues the preposition with substance. The other argument, an optional argument, can modify the meaning of the preposition itself.

In the case of *nearly in*, the meaning of *in* takes on a distinct change.  It no longer means *in*. It means something like, not in but in an area that is close to being in. Similarly, in the case of *ago next Tuesday*, the meaning of *ago* is changed.  It no longer is *ago* measured from the implicit *now*. It is *ago* measured from an explicit *next Tuesday*. That modified form of *ago* is what then acts upon the complement *ten years*.

Thus, *ten years ago next Tuesday* essentially has the same structure as *nearly in the soup*, but the sequence of the members of the structure are reversed:  Complement-Preposition-Adjunct vs. Adjunct-Preposition-Complement. Perhaps, when dealing with a post-positional, that sort of inversion can be expected and may even be necessary. Absent the preposition intervening between the complement and the adjunct, the phrase might be quite difficult to parse.

That takes me full circle to the sentence in the title of this post: *Our nation declared independence 246 years ago tomorrow.*  I believe *tomorrow* modifies the preposition *ago*.

While I am sure papers must exist on this subject, I have not yet found one.  Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I would advise reducing the length of the question, it shows research and effort but you ask a lot of questions together. Users are encouraged to answer their own questions too, so perhaps consider turning your reflections and analysis into a single answer and posting that.

Comment: In, for example, "Our wedding was [ten years ago tomorrow]", the bracketed "ago" phrase functions as predicative complement to "be". "Ten years" is object complement of "ago", and "tomorrow" is probably best analysed as modifier of "ago".

Comment: The Sentence seems grammatically "incorrect" !! I think that should be Either "**By** tomorrow, our nation **would have** declared independence 246 years ago" OR "Our nation declared independence 246 years ago **from** tomorrow" !!

Comment: I'm considering the paraphrase '10 years ago measuring backwards from tomorrow / Thursday' for '10 years ago from tomorrow / Thursday'. Here, the nouns tomorrow / Thursday etc specify the temporal zero chosen.

Comment: @BillJ's got it. The phrase <TimeLength> _ago_ <TimePoint> (_5 years ago yesterday, 100 years ago next Wednesday_) is a very common construction to refer to a fixed length of past time with a nearpresent endpoint.

Comment: FYI, it's only okay to say "he" here, if you are sure the person is a he.

Comment: @Prem It's perfectly unremarkable. And perfectly grammatical. It's a very common construction.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thank you.  Noted, and appreciated.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth's comment makes me question whether the NP before "ago" is even a complement of ago.  Might it be that in "ten years ago", "ago" is an intransitive PP (with an unstated "from now" complement) and that "ten years" is an adjunct modifier of "ago"?  See Aarts, Oxford Modern English Grammar,  § 5.5.2.  In that case, the "tomorrow" in my question would be the explicit complement of a transitive version of "ago".   With that in mind, can anyone point to proof that "ago" truly is a post-positional?

Comment: @BillJ, thank you.

Comment: @Prem, I agree that the construct has an old-fashioned sound, but I do encounter in everyday life.

Comment: I think this is "very common" and "acceptable" (I have heard it & used it!) , but not "grammatical" ; Similar to "I stayed home yesterday because [of] [certain] reasons" , where the [of] can be removed & the [certain] is also removed sometimes ; In OP Example, there are some words missing , but still it makes sense because of common usage & thus it is acceptable ! In "246 yeas ago [from] tomorrow" , the [from] is removed ; @tchrist ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality#Grammaticality_versus_acceptability

Answer (score 2):

> Our nation declared independence 246 years ago tomorrow.

I'm not convinced that "246 years ago tomorrow" is, as you seem to be positing, a syntactic constituent. You can, after all, rearrange them to get "Tomorrow our nation declared independence 246 years ago"; that version sounds acceptable to me, if a bit awkward. It seems to me that (syntactically) we have to take "tomorrow" and "246 years ago" to both be adjuncts in the clause (in more traditional terminology, both are acting adverbially, modifying *declared*).

Things get a bit more complicated when you add a *from*:

> Our nation declared independence 246 years ago from tomorrow.

Here it seems obvious that "246 years ago from tomorrow" is a constituent. Likewise with "Ten years ago from when" in your previous example. It seems we should take both "246 years" and "from tomorrow" to be complements of *ago*. There's nothing exceptional about a preposition taking two complements: consider the word *across* in "Across the road from the post office there is a children's playground" (Huddleston & Pullum (2002), p. 641). Here the word *across* has two complements: one is a NP ("the road") and the other is a PP ("from the post office"). The only unusual thing is that the preposition *ago* follows, rather than precedes, its first complement--as it does when it has only that complement, e.g. in "246 years ago" on its own (*ibid* p. 632). For this reason, we have "246 years ago from tomorrow" rather than "ago 246 years from tomorrow" (as with *across*).

Comment: Your reformulation of the sentence does not work for me at all and simply does not mean the same thing. [We also need to be very careful with *ago*. It is not the case that the measure-phrase complement of *ago* is a normal type of prepositional complement but in a different place. It has the same semantic contribution to the PP as a measure phrase modifier does in other ones: ***ten feet** behind the line*, for example, but it happens to be mandatory in the case of *ago.* It isn't an anchor to which another NP's oriented. The anchor for *ago* is usually an unexpressed *now* or *from*-PP].