# What do the adverbs modify?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbs, modifiers, grammatical-roles, measure-phrases

> They crashed the ship three years *later*.
> They crashed the ship three years *ago*.

In these sentences, do “later” and “ago” modify “crashed”? Also does “three years” modify “ago” and “later” since it tells how long ago and how much later?

Comment: Neither of them are modifiers; they are both complements. In the NP "Three years later", the adverb "later" is a complement as evident from the fact that if it is dropped the sentence becomes ungrammatical. "Ago" is an unusual preposition in that it follows its complement; in the PP "three years ago", the NP "three years" is complement of "ago".

Comment: @BillJ *Later* appears to be heading an adjunct in *They crashed the ship [three years] later*, where it heads the AdvP *three years later*. Within that AdvP, the measure phrase *three years* is a modifier of the head adverb *later.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postpositions in English and "ago"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/postpositions-in-english-and-ago)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I think you're right. As a modifier of "later", the NP "three years" can be dropped with no loss of grammaticality.

Comment: 'They bought the 'Nautilus' in 1788. They crashed the ship _three years later [than the time just referred to]_.' It is perhaps more helpful to see 'three years later than the time just referred to' or its usual deleted form 'three years later' as a temporal stating when _they crashed the ship_. 'Modify' is usually defined narrowly in linguistics, and doesn't mean 'refer to' in all cases.